# xmlhttprequest for pdf file works for sync but not async

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm testing out some code to scrape PDFs from a chrome extension by capturing user-clicked links.  Synchronous xmlhttprequest works on links to both html documents and pdfs.  However, asynchronous seem to never return.  Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Here's a minimal demonstrative example of my content.js in the failing async version:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

function getlink(link) {
    console.log("looking for link");
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", link, true);
    x.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("loaded");
        console.log(link);
        console.log(x.status);
    };

    x.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(x.statusText);
    };

    x.send(null);
}

for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    var l = links[i]
    l.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(this.href);
        getlink(this.href);
    }, false);
};
```

with that code, when a link to a html document is clicked, it logs, as expected, "looking for link", "loaded," the url, and "200".  And that's also what it logs when I rewrite this code to just fetch synchronously (by switching the last argument to the `open` method to true, and moving all the logging code out of an `unload` to the calling function.

But when I fetch a pdf asynchronously, it just says "looking for link" and then silence---no error, no response. It does give me a message:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "[URL TO PDF]".

but I'm not sure if that comes from the javascript link capture, or the ordinary browser click action.

Does anyone have any insight here?  Unfortunately, I think I have to do this async...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In synchronous mode the PDF is fetched before the default link event handler sees the click event.

In asynchronous mode the browser first handles the click event and loads the PDF file in current tab, so the original page is destroyed with all its event handlers and callbacks.

**Method 1:** use a [background (event) page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) script:

- define a message listener: `chrome.runtime.onMessage` in the background page that will fetch the PDF asynchronously
- in the click handler send a message with the PDF url using `chrome.runtime.postMessage`

**Method 2:** disable the default click behavior:

```
    l.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation(); // may be needed if the page has a custom event handler
        //e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // same reason
        console.log(this.href);
        getlink(this.href);
    }, false);
    .........
```

And maybe do the navigation once the PDF is fetched:

```
function getlink(link) {
    .........
    x.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("loaded");
        console.log(link);
        console.log(x.status);
        window.location.href = link;
    };
    .........
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that.  Out of curiosity in the meantime, why doesn't loading a new HTML page also destroy the context in async?

Comment: It always does, unless by `new HTML page` you mean a dynamically loaded page via AJAX and/or [history state manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

Comment: huh, but the async function works as expected when I'm clicking on a link to load a new html page, only fails on pdf...

Comment: Maybe because it takes much more time to load the PDF in XMLHttpRequest, whereas an HTML page (being small) is fetched before the browser destroys the window and document objects of the original page.

Comment: Well, whatever the reason for that particular html/pdf divergence mystery, your fix (method 2 --- my code needs to be executed from the original page) worked like a charm, so thank you!